# Ruby On Rails Mocha Expects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing

I have a function which I'm trying to test

```
@@described_class.expects(:foo).with(
  1,
  2,
  <any number>
)

@@described_class.bar()
```

so here my function `bar` calls `foo`. Is there a way to set this up where `:foo's` third parameter can be any number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the question title and the code snipped I'm assuming you're using this version of [mocha](https://github.com/freerange/mocha/).

If that's the case then you can pass a block to your `with` and define your expectations in there, see the [docs here](http://gofreerange.com/mocha/docs/Mocha/Expectation.html#with-instance_method).

```
object = mock()
object.expects(:expected_method).with() { |value| value % 4 == 0 }
object.expected_method(16)
# => verify succeeds

object = mock()
object.expects(:expected_method).with() { |value| value % 4 == 0 }
object.expected_method(17)
# => verify fails
```

The documentation doesn't have an example with more than one parameter as input, but given Ruby's nature I'd assume something like this would work

```
@@described_class.expects(:foo).with { |first, second, third| first == 1 && second == 2 }
```